Clarity on rpc flag design to pass boolean arguments
I am working with RPCs flags that may have a boolean argument which is extracted using GetBoolArg and there are various ways to pass Boolean arguments. For example
-fastprune=1     // true
-fastprune=0     // false
-fastprune       // true 
-fastprune=abc   // true
-nofastprune    // false

(please correct me if any one of them is wrong or if there are more)

Why is there no consistensy in tests to pass the arguments like =1/=0 for true/false or just pass the flag for true and don't pass it for false ? This adds to confusion and adds unnecessary extra cases ! Is there any other rationale behind it excluding backward compatibilty ?

-stopatheight is an integer argument though, not boolean?

@VojtěchStrnad thanks for pointing out. Replaced it with boolean rpc.

There are some good points here. However, as the final sentence makes clear, this is opinion based. See [tour] regarding opinion based questions.

@RedGrittyBrick thanks for pointing it out. Updated my question !

Is the question about the accepted options, or about the tests?

@PieterWuille . The question is targeted towards why are there these many options instead of 2 standard ones.
